# Eclipse Short Cut: File Search

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have looked and looked but I cannot find a shortcut for "File Search" in Eclipse.

I even downloaded the [mousefeed plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed).  *(It is pretty cool whenever you do something with the mouse.  A little popup comes up and tells you how you could have done that with a shortcut.  Not super useful but somewhat useful.)*

Comment: CTRL-H, then switch to tab file (see [eclipse file search](help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-45.htm)).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to unset the "When:" value?  I'm wanting to use CTRL-Shift-F for "file search" and it keeps getting overridden by the general shortcut for "Format Source".  No "Conflicts" are showing, though, so I'm guessing it's something to do with the "When:" dropdown that seems have no Global option........

Answer (score 50):

ctrl + H opens the search dialogue box. Click on customize and check the option 'Remember last used page'. First time you have to select the tab file search and perform a search. After that if you press ctrl + H , it will automatically point to file search tab.

Comment: This should be default in Eclipse.

Answer (score 13):

There is none, but if you go to Windows - Preferences - General - Keys, and type File search in the filter text box, you'll then be able to select the File search action, and type your own key binding.

Answer (score 10):

You can change all shortcut keys in eclipse for instance:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys -> search: File Search -> Binding -> *what ever key combination you like.